# .py script to run at the startup

Tags: python, 17.04, startup, python3

I use 17.04 and rc.local is gone(I couldn't do it with rc.local anyway).

I just want this two commands to run at the startup;

```
cd Folder
python3 file.py
```

That's it. I looked all the similar answers here but I couldn't make it.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Use `python3 path/to/file.py` instead – doesn't just running it as an autostart application in the settings suffice?

Comment: hey @dessert the thing is rc.local is gone when 17.04 came out. But answer is much appreciated, I will give it a try that way.

Answer (score 0):

Not using 17.04, but under 16.04 there is a "Startup and Shutdown" item in "System Settings". There is an "Autostart" item under there that allows you to specify scripts or programs that you want to run at startup.

Comment: I don't use ubuntu with desktop experience, I'm on terminal but thank you for answering :)

Comment: @J.Doe That's information that belongs in your question!

Comment: @J.Doe please add information to your question!

Comment: Hey @George I kept it as simple as possible. I use ubuntu 17.04 terminal, I want to do something that will execute this two command in the startup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cronjob. 
Edit your cronjobs with `crontab -e`, and add the script to run
`@reboot /home/user/script.sh` as an example

It is best to use a full path to your script

Comment: OK, I'm testing it now.

Comment: yeah it didn't worked out.

Comment: Does the script do what you want when you simply run it from your terminal?  
You should make sure the script is executable: `chmod +x /home/user/script.sh`

Then try running /home/user/script.sh from the terminal and see if you get the desired result.

Comment: I tried but full path of to the file, is not working out for me.

Comment: This will not work if invoking your script from the command line does not do what you want. Even if you are not in `Folder`.    
If you haven't already, add the interpreter you are using at the top of the script. For example `#!/usr/bin/python3`. Or wherever you have python3.  
Use `chomd +x ` to make the script executable. 
Then try running your script. Just `/home/usr/script.py` without python3 at the beginning. 
If the script MUST run from the directory Folder, you can try changing it to use full paths as well